# Ways to make a D program faster

Tags: optimization, d, micro-optimization, dmd, ldc

I'm working on a very demanding project (actually an interpreter), exclusively written in D, and I'm wondering what type of optimizations would generally be recommended. The project makes heavy use of GC, classes, asssociative arrays, and pretty much anything.

Regarding compilation, I've already experimented both with DMD and LDC flags and LDC with `-flto=full -O3 -Os -boundscheck=off` seems to be making a difference.

However, as rudimentary as this may sound, I would like you to suggest anything that comes to your mind that could help speed up the performance, related or not to the D language. (I'm sure I'm missing several things).

Comment: Is source code published? It could be useful...

Comment: @user1365836 I'm sure one can find tons of "weird" parts in the codebase, but I guess it's one of the side-effects of being under development, and without any crucial optimizations, just *working*. In any case, here you are: https://github.com/arturo-lang/arturo

Comment: It's a big project. Did you try to profile it? Check: https://wiki.dlang.org/Development_tools#Profiling

Comment: @user1365836 Good point. I did try to profile it. But: when building it with `dub build --build=profile` for example, weird issues start popping up, like `statement not reachable`, etc in files coming from the dependencies (not my project) and I most definitely do not know how to deal with that - am I to start tweaking the downloaded source from other packages?!. Building with `dub build --build=profile-gc` on the other hand, compilation/linking goes fine, but I can see no output whatsoever (or I'm blind...). Any ideas?

Comment: "statement not reachable" is just a warning. Did you add ```"buildRequirements": ["allowWarnings"]``` to dub recipe?

Comment: @user1365836 Interesting catch. I had no idea warnings were treated as errors by default, so I hadn't even though of it. The thing is I added the `buildRequirements` you mention as a root option the `dub.json` (https://github.com/arturo-lang/arturo/blob/master/dub.json), but nothing changed. Then I tried the same thing but with LDC (`dub build --build=profile --compiler=ldc2`). Now, the whole process went fine. But I still cannot find any output. Where is the profiling output supposed to be found?

Comment: I guess it should be saved on trace.log when you start your app.

Comment: @user1365836 from what I can tell DMD ignores the `buildRequirements` wherever I put them (I build with `--verbose` and the `-w` flag is still there, meaning warnings treated as errors), while when I directly use the `-wi` flag, it tells me to use the `allowWarnings` options. LDC ignores it too. However, when i add `-fprofile-generate` to my `dflags-ldc`, a `default.profraw` file is created... which looks supposedly good (not that I know what to do with it, other than trying `-fprofile-instr-use=` as suggested here: https://wiki.dlang.org/LDC_LLVM_profiling_instrumentation)

Comment: @user1365836 UPDATE (and an interesting discovery): when building with LDC and the `-fdmd-trace-functions` flags, it does finally produce a `trace.log` file! Let's see... :)

Comment: The common wisdom at the moment is that forget DMD if performance matters. I don't know if there is any significant difference between LDC and GDC but DMD is inferior compared to them. Disclaimer: I have only read this from the language forums, no any hands-on experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Compiler flags: I would add `-mcpu=native` if the program will be running on your machine. Not sure what effect `-Os` has in addition to `-O3`.
- Profiling has been mentioned in comments. Personally under Linux I have a script which dumps a process's stack trace and I do that a few times to get an idea of where it's getting hung up on.
- Not sure what you mean by GS.
- Since you mentioned classes: in D, methods are virtual by default; virtual methods add indirections and are not inlineable. Make sure only those methods that must be virtual are. See if you can rewrite your program using a form of polymorphism that doesn't involve indirections, such as using template metaprogramming.
- Since you mentioned associative arrays: these make heavy use of the GC; to speed them up, switch to a third-party library that works on top of std.allocator, such as https://github.com/dlang-community/containers
- If some parts of your code are parallelizable, std.parallelism is a good tool for this.
- Since you mentioned that the project is an interpreter: there are many avenues for optimizing them, up to JIT/AOT compilation. Perhaps you could link to an existing library such as LLVM or libjit.

Comment: If it's like GCC or Clang, the last one probably takes precedence.  Optimizing for code-size is usually not faster than speed.  It's not *supposed* to be, unless instruction-cache misses or similar effects are a performance problem, but sometimes there are compiler optimization bugs that lead to poor decisions.  e.g. branchless code when smaller branchy code would have been faster, or vice versa.  (Compiling "cold" functions with optimize-for-size can be good, but LTO means everything is re-optimized anyway).  Anyway, +1 for `-march=native` or the D equivalent.

Comment: Does the D compiler have profile-guided optimization?  With gcc you can build a C program with `gcc -O3 -march=native -fprofile-generate`, run the executable with a few representative inputs, then `gcc -O3 -march=native -fprofile-use` and it will unroll hot loops, and keep cold loops compact.

Comment: PGO is a backend feature, so GDC and LDC should have it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know we were talking about a compiler with the GCC back-end.  I thought DMD (like the OP asked about) had its own backend.  Is that why it uses  `-mcpu=native` instead of GCC-style `-march=native`?.  (I don't use D, but I've heard some about it.)  Anyway, LLVM does PGO, so LDC will have it.

Comment: `-mcpu=native` is an LDC (`ldmd`) switch. I don't know why that works and `-march=native` doesn't there.

Comment: @ "Not sure what you mean by GS" I meant GC - it was a typo. Regarding classes and virtual functions, I know they have a big overhead but not really sure how to change that. I've experimented with turning the whole thing to structs (basically my "Value" class which is being used *a lot*), but it had the opposite effect. Now, I'm experimenting with converting some of the methods to "pure", whenever this is possible, but I'm not sure the compiler - LDC or DMD - takes that into account. Any suggestions are more than welcome! :)

Comment: I don't think `pure` drives any compiler optimizations in any implementation at the moment. Walter Bright proposed a change in DMD to run `pure` functions at CTFE when possible, but optimizing compilers already do some form of CTFE as an optimization.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: For C/C++, GNU C supports [`__attribute__((const))` (and the weaker `pure`)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html), which allows `int foo = purefunc(x)` to be CSEd, e.g. hoisted out of a loop if `x` is loop invariant, even without inlining.  So at least the GCC back-end has support for something like that, if D "pure" methods are at all similar.

Comment: Re:experimental Allocator & using the new containers, namely HashMap and DynamicArray, here is some very weird conclusion: I ran many benchmarks testing regular associative arrays vs HashMaps: insert, find, etc and the results were rather impressive (like 2x-3x faster). Then I decided to change it in my symbol table (instead of storing my symbol-value pars in an associative array, I stored it in a HashMap). However, the results when running some intensive tests were disappointing - like 2x *slower*, and I cannot see why... since the operations were practically the same, only at a larger scale.

Comment: Make sure to have a good hashing function and that the hashmap size is adequate. Use a profiler to check why it's slow, e.g. if it's due to many collisions or something else.